# checkboxs responding slowly in ie6/7/8

Tags: jquery-1.8

I meet the simlar question today.There is about 100 checkbox in a page with jquery 1.8.1 ,it works fine in ff and chrome,and responsing very slowly in ie.After change jquery to 1.8.3,it worked good in ie.

I do not know why this happend.will any guys can tell me ?

Comment: If updating jQuery helped, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look on the changelog for 1.8.2 and 1.8.3 if the changes affect something in your code: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/09/20/jquery-1-8-2-released/ & http://blog.jquery.com/2012/11/13/jquery-1-8-3-released/

Comment: I think you don't only have to look on code changes referring directly to the checkboxes, but maybe some event handlers which get fired very often and got faster or something similat.